# Color operations in less

Tags: css, colors, less, converters

I'm already using color theme in my website, where, for example I have a standard hex color for link states regular/hover/active.

Now I want to use color operations in LESS like `color:darken(@base_color, x%);`

**So my question is:**

If I know my base color and my output color after the 'darken' operation,

how do I know what % to give the darken operation to produce my output color?

eg: If i'm going from #952262 -> #681744 what would be my %?

Maybe there's a site that does these conversions?

Hopefully the answer is not 'Trial and error'.

Comment: Incase anyone's interested there's a site that does exactly this in sass: http://razorjam.github.io/sasscolourfunctioncalculator/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Has A Few Challenges and Caveats

Normally, people do not use a function like `darken()` to get a color that they already know they want to end up at (they just put the color value they already know they want). However, I will assume there is more behind this question than that.

**The `darken()` Function**

[The `darken()` function of LESS](http://www.lesscss.org/#reference) affects the "brightness" or "lightness" portion of a color considered from the viewpoint of its `hsl` settings (hue, saturation, lightness). Here's your two colors considered from that view ([based on this site](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm), I have noticed some variations between sites--some are probably more accurate than others):

```
#952262 = hsl(327, 63%, 36%)
#681744 = hsl(327, 64%, 25%)
```

So the darkness value you seek can be *hand* calculated from that site, by just a subtraction, `36% - 25% = 11%`. Plugging that into your function:

```
darken(@base_color, 11%);
```

Yields

```
#671844 /* not 681744! */
```

**Hey! That Didn't Match My Target!**

Notice that the `s` (saturation) value above shows as different by `1%` from your base to your target, which means that technically you cannot get from your base color to the target color purely through the `darken()` function. Instead, you either need to use another function to tweak the `s` value also, or your target should be adjusted slightly to the following (which keeps `s` at `63%`):

```
#681844 = hsl(327, 63%, 25%)
```

But that number (`#681844`) still does not match the LESS output (`#671844`). The website shows the LESS output as being `hsl(327, 62%, 25%)` (notice the saturation value dropped to `62%`). I suspect what this means is a difference in rounding calculations between the website calculations and the LESS function calculations. This may well be why your original number was off by `1%` on saturation as well, whatever program you used rounded differently than the website also. This is probably not a big issue, as it gets you close to your target value.

**Using LESS to Calculate It**

Now, depending on what your actually doing, you can use LESS to calculate that percentage, instead of hand calculating it, using the `lightness()` function. Assume you had adjusted your target to `#681844` based off the website. Then this is an example of getting the percentage you want (I use a fake property `color-calc` to show the calcuation:

```
@base_color: #952262;  /* Base #952262 = hsl(327, 63%, 36%) */
@real_target_color: #681844; /* Real Target #681844 = hsl(327, 63%, 25%) */
@color_calc: (lightness(@base_color) - lightness(@real_target_color));

.test {
  color-calc: @color_calc;
  color: darken(@base_color, 11%);
}
```

Outputs:

```
.test {
  color-calc: 11%;
  color: #671844;
}
```

Notice that it calculated the `11%` difference in darkness. Also, notice that it still ends up with a value slightly different than target because of that (I suppose) rounding issue. Plugging in the final value LESS generates (`#671844`) as the target still yields the same `11%` value for `darken()`.

Comment: And it seems like we independantly came up with more or less the same solution, but you worked yours out a bit more and added the suggestions/warnings, +1 for your effort, you win ;-)

Comment: Just in case in Less 1.7.3 they have disabled rounding on those functions output so now it's more easy to get exact hex/rgb/hsl values (there's still some drift possible due to floating point presicion error because of hsl<->rgb conversion).

Answer (score 8):

LESS has the function **`lightness()`**, that returns the lightness channel of  a color in the hsl space.

So, obviously

```
lightness(hsl(90, 100%, 50%))
```

would return

```
50%
```

but you can do something more sophisticated, like a mixin, that calculates the lightness difference between two colors:

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;
@lighter-blue: #6F92B7;

.test(@color1, @color2) {
  @lightdif: (lightness(@color1) - lightness(@color2));
  color1: @color1;
  color2: @color2;
  lightness-dif:  @lightdif;
}

.test {
   .test(@lighter-blue, @nice-blue);
   output-color: lighten(@nice-blue, @lightdif);
}
```

which would return:

```
.test {
  color1: #6f92b7;
  color2: #5b83ad;
  lightness-dif: 6%;
  output-color: #6f92b7;
}
```

In your case (#952262 -> #681744) the `lightness-dif` would be 11%.

Now you can play with this a little, for example with guards, you can define which color is darker/lighter and use the absolute difference, depends on what exactly you want to use it for.

For more color operations you can read [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/#docs) under "Function Reference" -> "Color functions".

And if you are using a javascript implementation of less you can do even more using javascript interpolation (with back-ticks) and javascript functions inside LESS.

Comment: Looks like we both were working up detailed answers at about the same time :-).

Answer (score 7):

I created a [tool that suggests color functions](http://blog.gyoshev.net/cuttle/), since this bugs me on a daily basis. It lists most of the LESS functions that get from one color to another, so that you can focus on whether using `darken` or `softlight` with a color, makes more sense in terms of your design.

[image: Suggest color function transition]