# Given two colors, both in HSV(B), how can I convert one to another using LESS CSS?

Tags: colors, less

I'm designing some colored blocks, where the text is one color and the background is a lighter / desaturated shade of that same color (think warning text, where the words is red and it has a light pinkish background).

The text color is #990000. The background color is #f2dede. In Photoshop HSV, that equates to hsv(  0, 100%,  60%) & hsv(0, 8%, 95%).

With this color set, I'd like to be able to toss in other colors -- a nice green or yellow -- and have the background automatically calculated.

Using LESSCSS, I've tried:

```
@color: desaturate( lighten( hsv(0, 100%, 60%), 35%), 92% );
```

But I can't get it to render the color I generate by performing the same changes in Photoshop.

The color theory of this is beyond my comprehension, but my question is: How do I convert one color to another color, given the Photoshop HSB values?

**Update**:

I get it a little better -- the L and the B in HSB and HSL are not at all compatible, so lightening the color the "B" delta is never going to work.

It's sloppy, but something like this works:

```
@foreground: #990000;
@background: hsv(hsvhue(@foreground), 
    (hsvsaturation(@foreground)-92%), 
    (hsvvalue(@foreground)+35%));
```

Lacking a "value" command similar to lighten/darken, I'm thinking this is the best I'm going to get. (If I don't get any other responses, I'll mark this the answer).

Thanks much...Nate

Comment: there is no `hsv` colorspace in html, it's either `rgb` or `hsl`. So Why don't you just use `rgb` when you already have `rgb` in hex `#990000`->`rgb(153,0,0)`.

Comment: There's no HSV color space in HTML, but there is in LESS, and there is in Photoshop. I'm using HSV since LESS has hue, saturation and lightness commands. I'd be happy to ask the same question for RGB, though. If I have two RGB colors, and I want to calculate, using LESS CSS's saturate, lightness and hue commands, how do I figure out the numbers? The goal is to develop the "algorithm" so I can throw any color at it and have a nice, matching background color generated dynamically.

Comment: you can use the less color modifiers also for rgb colors. you don't need to transform it first. For the algorithm you could take the first google hit: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm ...

Comment: Hm. I'm not being clear. If I have two colors, how, other than trial and error, do I figure out how to convert from one to the other using LESSCSS commands (spin, etc)? I have #990000 and it looks nice on top of #f2dede. I want to figure out the set of LESS commands that makes that happen so I can arbitrarily change #990000 and have the background still have appropriate contrast, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: [my answer here discusses some issues with color theory and LESS functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314009/color-operations-in-less/16319785#16319785) that you may find useful also.

### For LESS 1.4 (which has some new built in functions)

**LESS**

```css
@color: hsv(0, 100%, 60%);
@bkg: hsv(hsvhue(@color), (hsvsaturation(@color) - 92%), (hsvvalue(@color) + 34.75%));

.test {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bkg;
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.test {
  color: #990000;
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
```

The link I posted above may explain why my value is `34.75%` and not `35%` more like your numbers were expecting.

**UPDATE: I just noticed that you had essentially posted a similar answer in your question.** I'm not certain exactly what issue you are still facing with that method of calculation.

**UPDATE 2:** If you desire it to generally always "contrast" then something like this may work better:

```css
@color: hsv(0, 100%, 60%);
@darkerBkg: hsv(hsvhue(@color), (hsvsaturation(@color) - 92%), (hsvvalue(@color) + 34.75%));
@lighterBkg: hsv(hsvhue(@color), (hsvsaturation(@color) + 92%), (hsvvalue(@color) - 34.75%));
@bkg: contrast(@color, @darkerBkg, @lighterBkg, 43%);

.test {
  color: @color;
  background-color: @bkg;
}
```

Using the `contrast` function with the default `43%` threshold value will cause a "flip" to the `@lighterBkg` in this case at a `35%` saturation value (`hsv(0,35%,60%)`).

The calculation numbers you have set are going to work best with colors in the initial saturation range of `92-100` (or with the `contrast` feature also `0-8`), and initial value range of `0-65` (or with `contrast` you would probably be covered in any value range). In the `contrast` version, any saturation between `9-91` will begin to "equalize" to either `0%` or `100%`. You would need to decide on a new "calculation" and add some other math logic in if that was an issue, but I think with the `contrast` version it may not be a problem.

Comment: what if you have a color `hsv(0,90%,66%)` -> `hsv(0,-2%,100.75%)` ?

Comment: The `hsv` function has limits on the upper and lower ends, so `hsv(0,-2%,100.75%)` ends up equal to `hsv(0, 0, 100%)` = `#ffffff` (you cannot get more "lighter / desaturated" as the OP wants than `white`). The solution is expecting a "darker" color in a certain value range for input to be compatible with making a similar numerical adjustment in order to be "automatically calculated" as the OP desires. Obviously the program cannot read the user's mind if the _calculation should change_ (it cannot be made to go from one arbitrary color to any other of the 16,777,216 possible colors).

Comment: @Christoph: I added a more robust version using the `contrast` function that would probably help to keep things more balanced while allowing a larger flexibility of valid inputs. It still boils down to the programmer probably cannot fully rely on a magic formula to _always_ get exactly what might be pleasing to the human eye of the end user without manually selecting and inputting the two fixed values desired.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I get that we need to "optically adjust" to get the most pleasing look, I'm just trying to get something close. The top-level "dark" colors all share the same SL, and are mostly just spins on the hue wheel. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Give this tool a try:

**Cuttle - Color function suggestions based on example**
https://www.ofcodeandcolor.com/cuttle/

It takes two different input colors and calculates (or approximates) different ways of going from one color to the other using Less or Sass color functions. Created by [@alex-gyoshev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25427/alex-gyoshev).

You'd have to convert your hsv values to rgb first, whilst taking into account the tipps from ScottS about the different color spaces.