# Calculate hue rotation from color A to color B

Tags: css, colors

Take a look at the following CSS:

```
.colorA{
    color:#ff0000;
}
.colorB{
    color:#ab123f;
}
.sameAsColorB{
    color:#ff0000;
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(...);
}
```

The goal is: given two hex-code colors, **how can one calculate the degree of rotation to turn the first into the second?** If this cannot always be accomplished by hue-rotate, what is a way that it can?

Comment: From my understanding of the hue rotation I draw the conclusion that you can´t get all colors. If you take a color and try to use the hue rotation to get an arbitrary color you will face the problem that they might not have the same radius. Hue rotation only rotates, it does not change the radius.

Comment: okay, but you can also change the saturation and many other aspects using the webkit filter, if you cannot do it solely with hue-rotate, how would one calculate all the necessary aspects?

Comment: You would need to check how every color is represented with polar coordinates. Then calculating angles and distances is rather simple.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314009/color-operations-in-less) - which uses css preprocessors for the calculation - may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't get all colors like that. In your example, you can't get color B from color A.

How you can turn one color into another is rather complicated and depends on each color. The following javascript function will give you the amount of red, green and blue that you will have in the new color if you start from green (#00ff00): (note: all angles are in radians)

```
function getcolors(x){
  var red = Math.sqrt(Math.cos(x+(Math.PI+1)/2)+1/2);
  var green = Math.sqrt(Math.cos(x)+1/2);
  var blue = Math.sqrt(Math.cos(x-(Math.PI+1)/2)+1/2);
  document.write("red: " + red + "<br/>green: " + green + "<br/>blue: " + blue);
}
```

The maximum a color can have is square root of 1.5. If you want the value in the normal 255 base, multiply it with 255 and divide it by square root of 1.5.

Write for example `getcolors(1)` to see what color you will get for`-webkit-filter:hue-rotate(1rad);`.

All primary colors (red, green and blue) work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution you can use in your razor view

```
@functions {
    string ToHueRotate(string startingColour, string targetColour)
    {
        var color1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(startingColour);
        var color2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(targetColour);

        int hue1 = (int)color1.GetHue();
        int hue2 = (int)color2.GetHue();

        int hueDifference = (hue2 - hue1 + 360) % 360;

        return hueDifference.ToString();
    }
} 




<style>
    .your-image-class {
        filter: hue-rotate(@ToHueRotate("#38cca5","#38cca5")deg);
    }
</style>
```